# opennlp Span class in eclipse java

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp, opennlp

I am new to java opennlp and i am trying to implement a program that extracts city names from a file but i am testing my code on a string first and i get some errors 
the code is

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;

 import main.java.opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
 import main.java.opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
 import main.java.opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;
 import main.java.opennlp.tools.util.Span;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.Tokenizer;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerME;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.TokenizerModel;
 import opennlp.tools.tokenize.SimpleTokenizer;
 import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
 import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;

  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

 public class CityFinder {

public String Tokens[];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException {

    CityFinder toi = new CityFinder();
    String cnt;
    cnt="John is planning to specialize in Electrical Engineering in UC Berkley and  pursue a career with IBM.";
    toi.tokenization(cnt);
    String cities = toi.namefind(toi.Tokens);
    String org = toi.orgfind(toi.Tokens);

    System.out.println("City name is : "+cities);
    System.out.println("organization name is: "+org);

}
    public String namefind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-location.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);
        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;

        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }
        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;
}

public String orgfind(String cnt[]) {
    InputStream is;
    TokenNameFinderModel tnf;
    NameFinderME nf;
    String sd = "";
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-ner-organization.bin");
        tnf = new TokenNameFinderModel(is);
        nf = new NameFinderME(tnf);
        Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);
        String a[] = Span.spansToStrings(sp, cnt);
        StringBuilder fd = new StringBuilder();
        int l = a.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
            fd = fd.append(a[j] + "\n");

        }

        sd = fd.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sd;

}
public void tokenization(String tokens) {

    InputStream is;
    TokenizerModel tm;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream("en-token.bin");
        tm = new TokenizerModel(is);
        Tokenizer tz = new TokenizerME(tm);
        Tokens = tz.tokenize(tokens);
        // System.out.println(Tokens[1]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

  }
```

and the errors i am getting with the span verialble
    Span sp[] = nf.find(cnt);
the error is Type mismatch: cannot convert from opennlp.tools.util.Span[] to main.java.opennlp.tools.util.Span[]
I don't know how to solve it in both locations

Any suggestions....??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should import all your classes from the packages within opennlp.tools package.

```
 import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
 import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
 import opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;
 import opennlp.tools.util.Span;
```